# Best way to post form data via ajax to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, forms

I'm just wondering what is the best way to post form data via ajax to a PHP script. I'm following these 3 methods:

1. Post form fields separately to PHP (And in PHP receive them individually like normal)
2. Convert form data into JSON encode data and send it to PHP in a single POST field ( And receive it in PHP as a single POST variable having JSON encoded data)
3. Convert form data into JSON encode data and send it to PHP in way that PHP receives it in `$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]`.

I would like to ask what is the best method in terms of security and performance. Is there any other better way to do this process? I repeat that I'm sending via jQuery AJAX.

Comment: [O'Reilly has](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596006563.do) an excellent book on PHP security, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm just wondering what is the best way to post form data via ajax to a PHP script.

Full stop. jQuery has solved this particular problem. Use [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and move on to more important things.

---

> I would like to ask what is the best method in terms of security and performance.

None of your methods is the "best" way. They are all worse than simply using what jQuery already gives you, and they are all *null* in terms of security and performance. Security and performance have *no* bearing on the code you've posted, these concepts are completely external to what you're trying to do, implemented at completely separate layers.

Security is completely irrelevant here. You're either using SSL and secure, or you're not using SSL and there is *no* security. There is no middle ground, and whatever method you use to post your data is completely unrelated to security. None of your methods is any more or less "secure" than any other.

For performance, the version that involves fewer HTTP requests is better. Posting the fields back individually is going to be *terrible* performance-wise, and I would imagine it's a nightmare to juggle data that way anyways. There is literally no advantage to posting back a form one field at a time that way. If I've misunderstood and you are talking about using a single HTTP POST for each method, then no method is any better.

Since you've tagged this with jQuery, use the jQuery way: [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) your form and post back the serialized data. You'll receive a normal array of posted data in `$_POST`. There is really no reason to do anything else, you're just adding complexity for no gain.

Comment: I think he meant individual fields in a single POST, not single fields in multiple POSTs.

Comment: Absolutely correct Blazemongerto. Exactly.

Comment: Thanks meager, I got the clearer picture now.

Answer (score 2):

As for performance: it's always better to minimize the number of requests. If you can send all the data in a single POST, you should. However, there's probably no good reason to send it all as a single field value. Just send them as separate fields for clarity, and process them server-side as if you were receiving an ordinary form.

As for security: no method is any more secure than any other when using POST. Try `https:` to strengthen things here.

Comment: I would go the same way as you mentioned. Just sending it all as a normal form. It should be the fastest way of doing it.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and go a little bit deeper on why POST is secure? Would be nice. Thank you!

Comment: See meagar's answer re: security. I have nothing better to add to that.

Comment: @prc322 Post **isn't** secure. Using POST vs GET has absolutely nothing to do with security, even tangentially.

Comment: Actually i asked for security and performance both (if any). Since I was more concerned in using $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"].

Comment: If you're using an insecure connection, it doesn't matter. You're just creating security through obscurity, which isn't really security at all.

Comment: If you're using a single HTTP post for each method, *none* of your methods are better from a security or performance stand point. They are all different ways of doing the same thing. As I said in my answer, you should avoid all three of those methods and simply use jQuery's `serialize` or `serializeArray`. jQuery has solved this problem for you, and you gain nothing by reinventing this particular wheel.

Comment: Well this isn't quite true guys. i. e. JSON Hijacking can be prevented by using POST instead of GET in webservices. See: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/24/json-hijacking.aspx Of course it's not the holy grail of security for web apps but POST under some situations can create at least some security by design since it cannot simply be run with a browser by just calling an HTTP resource like with GET.